# not able to display text like typewriter effect using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html

when I am running the code on a live server it's showing undefined instead of displaying the text I wanted to display. i am not able to resolve the issue behind this.

```
    <body>
        <div id="name">

        </div>

        <script>
           window.onload=  init();

          var i=0;
           function init(){
            var elem= document.querySelector('#name');
            i= i+1;
           console.log(i);
            var arr= ['k', 'a', 'r', 'a', 'n'];
           elem.innerHTML += arr[i]; 

            if(i<arr.length){
                requestAnimationFrame(init);
            }


           }




        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to figure out what you want to do... try this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
            <p id="name"></p>
            
            <script>
              var i=0;
              var text = "karan is the text i want to display"
              window.onload= init()
              function init() {
               document.getElementById('name').innerHTML += text.split("")[i];
               i++
                if (i<text.length)
                window.requestAnimationFrame(init)
              }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: i wanted to do using requestAnimationFrame

Comment: 2 blocking error : You call `init()` before declaring and initilizing i. You increment i before use it in you function